# Request header in rest webservice as Object

Tags: java, rest, web-services

I want to send request header on Rest web-service , not as String but as a Custom Object, there is anyway to do that?

Answer (score 0):

No, an HTTP header must be a string. See https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers

> HTTP headers allow the client and the server to pass additional information with the request or the response. A request header consists of its case-insensitive name followed by a colon ':', then by its value (without line breaks). Leading white space before the value is ignored.

But you can encode a custom object in a header, for example using JSON + base64

```
 CustomHeader: eyJhIjoiYiJ9     // {"a":"b"} in base64
```